# datatables pagination is broken when I add sType

Tags: sorting, pagination, datatables

Im using the date-euro plugin to sort the date column properly. the sort is working, but the pagination is going to broken on init when I add the sType parameter. when i click the numberofelement dropdown or on the next button, the pagination works. The prettydaterender function converts the date from 2012-10-24 14:00 to 24/10/2012 14:00
Could you help me please?

```js
$.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-euro-pre": function ( a ) {
        if ($.trim(a) != '') {
            var frDatea = $.trim(a).split(' ');
            var frTimea = frDatea[1].split(':');
            var frDatea2 = frDatea[0].split('/');
            var x = (frDatea2[2] + frDatea2[1] + frDatea2[0] + frTimea[0] + frTimea[1] + frTimea[2]) * 1;
        } else {
            var x = 10000000000000; // = l'an 1000 ...
        }

        return x;
    },

    "date-euro-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return a - b;
    },

    "date-euro-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return b - a;
    }
} );
table.dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    'aaSorting': [[3, 'desc']],
    'aoColumns': [null,null,null,{
        // 14:43 24/10/2012
        'fnRender': prettyDateRender,
        'sType': 'date-euro-desc'
    }]
});
```